# Python помогите пожалуйста найти ошибку в коде

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import random

# Создание игрового поля
board = []

for _ in range(5):
    row = ['O'] * 5
    board.append(row)

# Функция для отображения игрового поля
def display_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print(' '.join(row))

# Функция для создания случайной позиции корабля
def random_row(board):
    return random.randint(0, len(board) - 1)

def random_col(board):
    return random.randint(0, len(board[0]) - 1)

# Генерация позиций кораблей
ship_row = random_row(board)
ship_col = random_col(board)

# Игровой цикл
for turn in range(4):
    print(f'Ход {turn + 1}')

# Ввод координат выстрела
guess_row = int(input('Укажите номер строки: '))
guess_col = int(input('Укажите номер столбца: '))
board[guess_row][guess_col] = 'Y'

# Проверка на попадание
if guess_row not in range(5) or guess_col not in range(5):
        print('Упс! Это не в пределах игрового поля!')
    if board[guess_row][guess_col] == 'Y':
        print('Вы уже стреляли в эту клетку!')
    if guess_row != ship_row or guess_col != ship_col:
        print('Мимо!')
    if (turn + 1) == 4:
        print('Игра окончена!')
        display_board(board)
    if guess_row == ship_row and guess_col == ship_col:
        print('Поздравляю! Вы потопили корабль!')
break
```

Comment: А может, там и нет ошибки? Вопрос должен быть конкретным, с описанием проблемы

Comment: А вы знаете что такое "debugger"?

Comment: Судя по всему, не знает...

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой (**«почему этот код не работает?»**) должны включать желаемое поведение, *конкретную проблему или ошибку* и *минимальный код* для её воспроизведения **прямо в вопросе**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так, по порядку:
Код выполняет ввод и проверку только один раз, после чего сразу переходит к завершению игры. Необходимо переместить ввод и проверку внутрь цикла for turn in range(4):

В коде отсутствует правильное использование операторов условия. Вместо этого используйте операторы if, elif и else для правильной проверки условий и выполнения соответствующих действий.

Используется оператор break, но он находится вне цикла. break должен быть внутри цикла для корректного завершения игры после достижения лимита ходов.

Исправленный код:

```
import random

# Создание игрового поля
board = []

for _ in range(5):
    row = ['O'] * 5
    board.append(row)


# Функция для отображения игрового поля
def display_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print(' '.join(row))


# Функция для создания случайной позиции корабля
def random_row(board):
    return random.randint(0, len(board) - 1)


def random_col(board):
    return random.randint(0, len(board[0]) - 1)


# Генерация позиций кораблей
ship_row = random_row(board)
ship_col = random_col(board)

# Игровой цикл
for turn in range(4):
    print(f'Ход {turn + 1}')

    # Ввод координат выстрела
    guess_row = int(input('Укажите номер строки: '))
    guess_col = int(input('Укажите номер столбца: '))

    # Проверка на попадание
    if guess_row not in range(5) or guess_col not in range(5):
        print('Упс! Это не в пределах игрового поля!')
    elif board[guess_row][guess_col] == 'Y':
        print('Вы уже стреляли в эту клетку!')
    elif guess_row != ship_row or guess_col != ship_col:
        print('Мимо!')
    else:
        print('Поздравляю! Вы потопили корабль!')
        break

if turn + 1 == 4:
    print('Игра окончена!')
    display_board(board)
```

Comment: спасибо огромное, за то что поправили код и за понятное объяснение